# Separate time series regressions or a panel (with dummies)?

Tags: regression

What is the difference between running N separate time series regressions relative to running a panel (POLS for example) with and without dummies for the N entities? It would be useful to get some intuition about the impact on the coefficients and standard errors.

Comment: I understand your question as whether to fit a model with all observations or split the observations into n subgroups and fit a model for each subgroup. Is this what you want to know? If yes, please make this clearer in the questions first (to avoid that I give an answer to a wrong question).

Comment: Yes. You can look at it this way. Fit a model on all observations vs fit a model on all observations with dummies for the subgroups vs a separate model for each subgroup. Thanks.

Comment: I have previously provided an answer to this question here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/299818/estimate-model-with-dummies-for-whole-sample-versus-model-without-dummies-for-ea/299911#299911 Hope that helps.

Comment: Tom, if you have an answer to another question that completely answers a given question you should normally flag it as a duplicate of the question you answered